# Box containing 4 black and 6 white marbles.

Tags: probability

Four marbles are drawn from the box at random without replacement.

Calculate the probability that at least two white marbles are drawn given that at least one of each colour is drawn.

I have calculated $P(A)$ the probability that at least two white marbles are drawn to be: $$P(A)=\frac{(6C4)(4C0)+(6C3)(4C1)+(6C2)(4C2)}{10C4}=\frac{185}{210}$$

I have calculated $P(B)$ the probability that at least one counter of each colour is drawn to be: $$P(B)=\frac{(4C3)(6C1)+(4C2)(6C2)+(4C1)(6C3)}{(10C4)}=\frac{194}{210}$$

I don't know where to go from here. The textbook gives an answer of $\frac{17}{21}$, but I have no idea where that came from. All help appreciated.

Comment: What is $\Pr(A\cap B)$, at least two white and one of each color?

Comment: I get $\frac{17}{21}$ for $P(A\cap B)$, not for $P(A|B)$